# I can iterate through my first iteration of PyTorch successfully, but am unable to do a second iteration. Please see code and error I get

Tags: python, pytorch

I can iterate through my first iteration of PyTorch successfully, but am unable to do a second iteration.  Please see my code and error I get if I were to run my code a second time through.

```
current_grad = 0
l_rate = 10**-4
x=torch.tensor([[1.0,2.,4.],[2.,3.,2.]])
y=torch.tensor([1.0,0.])
w=torch.tensor([.5,2.,1.], requires_grad=True)


# forward propagate
output = x @ w.T
y_pred = 1/(1+ math.e**-(output))

# objective function
loss = sum(y*(y_pred**.5) + ((1-y) * (1-y_pred)**.5)) / len(y_pred)

# now, get gradient over these layers 
x.requires_grad =True
y.requires_grad =True
w.requires_grad =True
loss.backward()

# update only 1 set of weights here.
with torch.no_grad():
    w = w + (w.grad * l_rate)

I get an error at my loss.backward line:   
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'float'
How can I fix this so that my w.grad is not NoneType on the second time around?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue with your code is that `w = w + (w.grad * l_rate)` is assigning a new variable to `w`.

Instead you need to update `w` in place.

```py
with torch.no_grad():
    w.copy_(w + w.grad * l_rate)
```

Some other issues

- Learning rate is much too small for this problem
- You need to zero the gradients of `w` after each step since `backwards` accumulates gradients.
- Setting `requires_grad` for `x` and `y` is unnecessary since you don't need the gradient of loss w.r.t. these tensors.
- In your code, the value of "loss" is actually something you want to maximize, since your objective function is maximal when y = y_pred. Generally we wouldn't call this loss, because that would imply you want to minimize it (only a masochist wants to maximize their loss :P).

Correcting for these issues

```py
import torch

l_rate = 0.1
x = torch.tensor([[1.0, 2., 4.], [2., 3., 2.]])
y = torch.tensor([1.0, 0.])
w = torch.tensor([.5, 2., 1.], requires_grad=True)

# training loop ...

# forward propagate
output = x @ w 
y_pred = torch.sigmoid(output)

# objective function
objective = torch.mean(y * (y_pred**.5) + ((1 - y) * (1 - y_pred)**.5))

# compute gradient of objective w.r.t. w
objective.backward()

with torch.no_grad():
    # gradient ascent
    w.copy_(w + (w.grad * l_rate))
    # zero the gradients
    w.grad.zero_()
```